# putItem is failing in the new PHP AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to learn the PHP AWS SDK, I installed it properly in my system
and configured the access and secret keys, I also logged in and created tables using the
console.

What I'm trying to do now is to add a row! simple as that! I downloaded to my kindle
the Amazon DynamoDB book and tried to read the API but maybe something changed in the new version since there is no AmazonDynamoDB class anywhere.

This is my code so far.

```
$dynamodb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
        'key'    => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
 ));

 $dynamodb->putItem(array('TableName'=>'LoginToken',
        'Item'=>array(
                'Uid' => array(AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER =>  $uid),
                'OAuth_Token' => array (AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => $oauth_token),
                'IpAdress' => array (AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => $ip_address)
                )
        ));
```

I tried to grep the entire vendor directory and it seems that this class really doesn't exist. 
How do I proceed? How do I add a row properly  ?

Comment: Which class doesn't exist? Can you provide an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Ok this was very easy to answer after all...
AmazonDynamoDB doesn't exist anymore..

So I grepped for STRING, and I found Type.php

So in order to solve issue like that you need to add

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\Type;
```

nd then you can use `Type::S` or `Type::String` or whatever.. just read the class file.
Didn't think about it till I posted the question.